# How to change a global variable within a function using click eventListener function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I try to change the variable of passLength using 4 different buttons. This will affect the length of the string result of the function. The problem I'm noticing is that when I press for example the "24" button, then run the main function with the (now commented out) console log, passLength still logs as the default of 16. I believe this is because it was declared globally at the beginning, and my changes on button click are not taking place since they are happening locally within functions. Because when I console log within the buttonclick functions, it always puts out the value I need.

So my question is: How do I change this global passLength variable with button clicks?

```js
let passLength = 16; //Default lngth of password. This will be changable later on

document.getElementById('btn8').addEventListener('click', function(){
    let passLength = 8;
    console.log(passLength)
    return passLength;
});
document.getElementById('btn16').addEventListener('click', function(){
    let passLength = 16;
    console.log(passLength)
    return passLength;
});
document.getElementById('btn20').addEventListener('click', function(){
    let passLength = 20;
    console.log(passLength)
    return passLength;
});
document.getElementById('btn24').addEventListener('click', function(){
    let passLength = 24;
    console.log(passLength)
    return passLength;
});


randomString(passLength)

function randomString(passLength){
    //console.log(passLength)
    var randomPassword = '';
    var characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-=+?!$/><)(%&*'
    for(var i, i = 0; i < passLength; i++){
        randomPassword += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length))
    };
    console.log(randomPassword)
    return randomPassword;
};

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('string').textContent = randomString(passLength);
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="contentWrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <h2>Generate a Secure Password</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="stringContainer">
                <p id="string">Click the button to start!</p> <!--password inside-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btnRow">
            <div id="generateButton">
                <button id="btn">Generate</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <!--empty row-->
        </div>
        <div class="h3Row">
            <h3>Select Number of Characters:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="selectingRow">
            <div class="selectorBtn">
                <button id="btn8" class="slctBtn">8</button>
            </div>
            <div class="selectorBtn">
                <button id="btn16" class="slctBtn">16</button>
            </div>
            <div class="selectorBtn">
                <button id="btn20" class="slctBtn">20</button>
            </div>
            <div class="selectorBtn">
                <button id="btn24" class="slctBtn">24</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#contentWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(177, 192, 177);
}

h2 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 4px 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
}

.btnRow {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 35px;
}

.h3Row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 25px;
}

.selectingRow {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 25px;
}

.slctBtn {
    min-height: 20px;
    min-width: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgb(255, 168, 168);
    transition: all 0.07s linear;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.slctBtn:hover { /*give this an animation later, maybe a little shake*/
    background-color: rgb(201, 99, 99);
}

.slctBtn:active { /*give this an animation too*/
    background-color: rgb(201, 99, 99);
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#generateButton {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#btn {
    min-height: 50px;
    min-width: 110px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: large;
    background-color: rgb(255, 168, 168);
    transition: all 0.07s linear;
}

#btn:hover { /*give this an animation later, maybe a little shake*/
    background-color: rgb(201, 99, 99);
}

#btn:active { /*give this an animation too*/
    background-color: rgb(201, 99, 99);
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#stringContainer { /*Box*/
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #636161;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#string {
    display: flex;
    letter-spacing: 2.1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-declaring `passLength` with `let` (block scope) within each event handler which creates new variables, rather than affecting the global one. Remove all the `let` declarations in each callback to affect the one Global.

```js
let passLength = 16; //Default lngth of password. This will be changable later on

document.getElementById('btn8').addEventListener('click', function(){
    passLength = 8;
    console.log(passLength)
    return passLength;
});
document.getElementById('btn16').addEventListener('click', function(){
    passLength = 16;
    console.log(passLength)
    return passLength;
});
document.getElementById('btn20').addEventListener('click', function(){
    passLength = 20;
    console.log(passLength)
    return passLength;
});
document.getElementById('btn24').addEventListener('click', function(){
    passLength = 24;
    console.log(passLength)
    return passLength;
});


randomString(passLength)

function randomString(passLength){
    //console.log(passLength)
    var randomPassword = '';
    var characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-=+?!$/><)(%&*'
    for(var i, i = 0; i < passLength; i++){
        randomPassword += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length))
    };
    console.log(randomPassword)
    return randomPassword;
};

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('string').textContent = randomString(passLength);
});
```

```css
html, body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#contentWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(177, 192, 177);
}

h2 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 4px 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
}

.btnRow {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 35px;
}

.h3Row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 25px;
}

.selectingRow {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 25px;
}

.slctBtn {
    min-height: 20px;
    min-width: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgb(255, 168, 168);
    transition: all 0.07s linear;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.slctBtn:hover { /*give this an animation later, maybe a little shake*/
    background-color: rgb(201, 99, 99);
}

.slctBtn:active { /*give this an animation too*/
    background-color: rgb(201, 99, 99);
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#generateButton {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#btn {
    min-height: 50px;
    min-width: 110px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: large;
    background-color: rgb(255, 168, 168);
    transition: all 0.07s linear;
}

#btn:hover { /*give this an animation later, maybe a little shake*/
    background-color: rgb(201, 99, 99);
}

#btn:active { /*give this an animation too*/
    background-color: rgb(201, 99, 99);
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#stringContainer { /*Box*/
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #636161;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#string {
    display: flex;
    letter-spacing: 2.1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentWrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <h2>Generate a Secure Password</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="stringContainer">
                <p id="string">Click the button to start!</p> <!--password inside-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btnRow">
            <div id="generateButton">
                <button id="btn">Generate</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <!--empty row-->
        </div>
        <div class="h3Row">
            <h3>Select Number of Characters:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="selectingRow">
            <div class="selectorBtn">
                <button id="btn8" class="slctBtn">8</button>
            </div>
            <div class="selectorBtn">
                <button id="btn16" class="slctBtn">16</button>
            </div>
            <div class="selectorBtn">
                <button id="btn20" class="slctBtn">20</button>
            </div>
            <div class="selectorBtn">
                <button id="btn24" class="slctBtn">24</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```